# How do i load commands from a folder and subfolder(s)?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my original code

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath);

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  if ( file.isDirectory() === true ) {
    const nestPath = path.join(__dirname, file)
    const cmdFiles = fs.readdirSync(file)
    for (const file2 of cmdFiles) {
      const filePath2 = path.join(commandsPath, nestPath, file2)
      const command2 = require(filePath2)
      client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    }
  } else {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
  }
}
```

i've been changing a lot of this code and just decided I'll send the original code i started with
What I'm trying to do is read the "commands" folder then any subfolders in it, and if possible even more nested folders.

My code here works for the files in the "commands" folder but when it enters the subfolder thats where it goes haywire

Comment: Looks like a copy&paste mistake. In the for-loop, where the file is a dic. (`file.isDirectory()`), u read the command with `const command2 = require(filePath2)` but in the line down below (`client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);`) u are using the var `command` and not `command2`.

Comment: Which error do you exactly get?

Comment: `TypeError: file.isDirectory is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise the following to fix your error about isDirectory:

This is a snippet of your above code, which includes console logging, so you can see what is produced, and therefore why the commands were failing.  An array of strings is returned from the readdirSync, these aren't objects.

```json
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath);
console.log(commandFiles)
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    console.log(file);
  if ( fs.lstatSync(`${commandsPath}/${file}`).isDirectory() === true ) {
```